Axiom of Choice and the cardinality of the index set
Suppose we have a collection of open intervals $\{(i,i+1): i\in I\}$ where $I$ is some index set. Do we need the Axiom of Choice (AC) to guarantee that we can choose an element from each interval if:

$I=\{1,2,\dots,k\}$ where $k$ is finite,
$I=\mathbb N$, and
$I=\mathbb R$?

Am I right in thinking that AC is not necessary in all three cases because one can use the function $f(r)=r+0.5$ to choose from each interval regardless of the cardinality of the index set? If so, how could this example be modified so that AC becomes necessary?

I think you're right about not needing AC, for that reason. There are multiple ways you could modify this to need AC; do you have any thoughts on this score?

Incidentally, a classic example is the set of equivalence classes in $\mathbb{R}$ induced by $x \sim y$ if $x$ and $y$ differ by a rational number.

@BrianTung Apart from its role in this, I love that example because, while any equivalence relation can be restated in the form $f(x)=f(y)$, that one is unusually resistant (at least for equivalence relations on numbers) to choices of $f$ not defined in terms of the relation's equivalence classes.

@spaceisdarkgreen: Could you elaborate? Or perhaps point me to a reference that proves your statement. Thanks

You are correct in saying that AC is not required in any of the three cases. The reason is that your collection is explicit enough that you can explictly write down a choice-function.
I should also note that AC will never be required when the index set is finite, as in the first case. This is because you can prove the Axiom of Choice when the index set is finite in ZF by using simple induction.
For a similar example, where you do need the axiom of choice, consider the following theorem:

Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, if $x$ is a limit point of $S$, then there exists a sequence $s_{n}$ consisting of elements of $S$, such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} s_{n}=x.$

The proof of this goes by considering sets of the form $A_{n}=\{s\in S: |x-s|<\frac{1}{n}\}$, where the index set is $\mathbb{N}$. Now, using the axiom of choice there exists a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to S$, such that $f(n)$ is an element of $A_{n}.$ This gives us a sequence converging to $x$. In this case, we had to use the Axiom of Choice because there simply no explicit way to pick an element from $A_{n}$. If we had more information about $S$, maybe we could do away with the Axiom of Choice. But when $S$ is a general subset, there is simply no way.
